# Does Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false) make sense in WinForms apps?

Tags: .net, winforms, gdi+, text-rendering, textrenderer

When we create a new WinForms app project in VS.NET, the following template code is used for the main procedure of the app:

```cs
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

What is the purpose of calling [Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setcompatibletextrenderingdefault(v=vs.110).aspx) with its `defaultValue` parameter set to `false` if all WinForms controls like Label and Button we place on forms have the `UseCompatibleTextRendering` property set to `false` by default?

Comment: No.  It was a compatibility option for programs written in .NET 1.x.  Without it such a program could look poorly in .NET 2.0 with text no longer fitting as it did back in 1.1.  Back-compat is pretty sacred to Microsoft.

Comment: Then the right way to process this situation is to add Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(**true**) to old programs that come from .NET 1.x. If we create a new app in VS 2005+, then the setting we are talking about is really useless, redundant and misleading. I thought there could be a hidden effect of doing Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false) in .NET 2.0+ apps I have not discovered yet...

Comment: Well, of course not.  A program written in 1.x days does not contain this call, the method did not exist yet.  So the default must be false to get back-compat behavior.  There is excessively little reason to fret about this, project templates for the past 13 years already do this without assistance.

Comment: @HansPassant, am I missing something? We get GDI+ rendering from .NET 1.x in WinForms controls if we call Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(true). But this is not the default mode of .NET 2.0+, which is equivalent to Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false).